Problem displaying the same image in several successive windows with Tkinter
As part of a Tkinter interface, I'm having a problem displaying an image with the error :
_tkinter.TclError: image "portrait_5" doesn't exist
Below is the code currently being written. It's not finished, as not all features have been implemented yet.
The idea is to configure a slot-race using the "configurer" menu, then to follow the slot-race using the "lancer" menu. The problem: in the 'lancer' interface, which will follow the race (number of laps, time, etc), I can't display the portrait (.png image) chosen by the drivers in 'configurer'.
Could this be due to the "after" function for the stopwatch and should it also work with "after" to retrieve lap times, etc.?
import tkinter
from tkinter import Tk, Entry, Menu, PhotoImage, Label, Frame, LabelFrame, Canvas, Listbox, Button, Image, messagebox, Toplevel
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import json

global ticks
ticks = 0
liste_voiture = ["Aston Martin Vantage GT3", "McLaren 720S GT3", "Dodge Viper GTS R", "Alfa Romeo 33/3 1972", "Alfa Romeo 33/3 1971" ]
liste_portrait = [ "Satanas panthère", "Folle du volant", "Sorcière sans balai", "Vieux à donf'"]
liste_portrait_photo = ["portrait_5", "portrait_6", "portrait_8", "portrait_7"]


def quitter():
    quit()

def config():
    global pilote1, pilote2, voiture1, voiture2, temps_course, portrait_pilote1, portrait_pilote2
    if pilote1.get() =="" or pilote2.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Configuration incorrecte", "Vous devez nommer les pilotes.")
        return
    course = {}
    fic = open('course.txt', 'w')
    course['Pilote 1'] = pilote1.get()
    course['Pilote 2'] = pilote2.get()
    n = voiture1.curselection()[0]
    course['Voiture 1'] = liste_voiture[n]
    m = voiture2.curselection()[0]
    course['Voiture 2'] = liste_voiture[m]
    if course['Voiture 1'] == course['Voiture 2']:
        messagebox.showerror("Configuration incorrecte", "Vous devez choisir des voitures différentes.")
        return
    o = portrait_pilote1.curselection()[0]
    course['Portrait pilote 1'] = liste_portrait_photo[o]
    p = portrait_pilote2.curselection()[0]
    course['Portrait pilote 2'] = liste_portrait_photo[p]
    course['Temps de course'] = int(temps_course.get())
    with open("configcourse.json", "w") as fic:
        json.dump(course, fic)
    fic.close()



fenetre_ppale = Tk()
fenetre_ppale.geometry("1720x1080+10+10")
fenetre_ppale.title("Data Slot Course V1")


# GESTION DES IMAGES
image1 = Image.open("images/alpha_romeo.png")
image2 = Image.open("images/flag.png")
fond = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
drapo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)

#GESTON DES LISTES
list_v = tkinter.Variable(value=liste_voiture)
list_p = tkinter.Variable(value=liste_portrait)


# GESTION CONFIGURATION

def configurer():
    global portrait_pilote1, portrait_pilote2, portrait_1, portrait_2, portrait_3, portrait_4, pilote1, pilote2, voiture1, voiture2, temps_course, frame3, frame4
    #frame3, frame4
    #GESTION DES IMAGES
    dessin1 = Image.open("images/portrait_satanas.png")
    dessin2 = Image.open("images/portrait_folle.png")
    dessin3 = Image.open("images/portrait_sorciere.png")
    dessin4 = Image.open("images/portrait_vieux.png")
    portrait_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(dessin1)
    portrait_2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(dessin2)
    portrait_3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(dessin3)
    portrait_4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(dessin4)

    # CARACTERISTIQUE DE LA FENETRE PRINCIPALE
    fenetre_ppale.title("Configuration d'une course")
    lbl_image.place_forget()

    # FORMULAIRE
    frame3 = Frame(fenetre_ppale, border=3, pady=0, padx=0, bg="whitesmoke")
    frame3.place(x=100, y=100, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.7)
    #NOM DU PILOTE 1
    label_pilote1 = Label(frame3, text = "PILOTE 1", font="Futura 24", bg="whitesmoke")
    label_pilote1.place(x=25, y=28)
    pilote1 = Entry(frame3, )
    pilote1.place(x=25, y=65)
    # NOM DU PILOTE 2
    label_pilote2 = Label(frame3, text="PILOTE 2", font="Futura 24", bg="whitesmoke")
    label_pilote2.place(x=500, y=28)
    pilote2 = Entry(frame3, )
    pilote2.place(x=500, y=65)
    # VOITURE DU PILOTE 1
    label_voiture1 = Label(frame3, text="VOITURE 1", font="Futura 24", bg="whitesmoke")
    label_voiture1.place(x=25, y=110)
    voiture1 = Listbox(frame3, listvariable=list_v, selectmode="SINGLE", exportselection=0, border=0, bg="whitesmoke")
    voiture1.place(x=25, y=150)
    # VOITURE DU PILOTE 2
    label_voiture2 = Label(frame3, text="VOITURE 2", font="Futura 24", bg="whitesmoke")
    label_voiture2.place(x=500, y=110)
    voiture2 = Listbox(frame3, listvariable=list_v, selectmode="SINGLE", exportselection=0, border=0, bg="whitesmoke")
    voiture2.place(x=500, y=150, )
    # PORTTRAIT DU PILOTE 1
    label_portrait1 = Label(frame3, text="PORTRAIT 1", font="Futura 24", bg="whitesmoke")
    label_portrait1.place(x=25, y=260)
    portrait_pilote1 = Listbox(frame3, listvariable=list_p, selectmode="SINGLE", exportselection=0, border=0, bg="whitesmoke")
    portrait_pilote1.place(x=25, y=300)
    # PORTTRAIT DU PILOTE 2
    label_portrait2 = Label(frame3, text="PORTRAIT 2", font="Futura 24", bg="whitesmoke")
    label_portrait2.place(x=500, y=260)
    portrait_pilote2 = Listbox(frame3, listvariable=list_p, selectmode="SINGLE", exportselection=0, border=0, bg="whitesmoke")
    portrait_pilote2.place(x=500, y=300)
    # TEMPS DE COURSE
    label_temps_course = Label(frame3, text="TEMPS COURSE", font="Futura 24", bg="whitesmoke")
    label_temps_course.place(x=250, y=400)
    temps_course = Entry(frame3, )
    temps_course.place(x=250, y=450)
    # CHOIX DES PORTRAITS
    frame4 = Frame(fenetre_ppale, border=3, pady=0, padx=0, bg="whitesmoke")
    frame4.place(x=950, y=100, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.7)
    satanas = Label(frame4, text="Satanas panthère", image=portrait_1, compound="top", border="0")
    satanas.place(x=20, y=20)
    folle = Label(frame4, text="Folle du volant", image=portrait_2, compound="top")
    folle.place(x=20, y=280)
    sorciere = Label(frame4, text="Sorcière sans balai", image=portrait_3, compound="top")
    sorciere.place(x=260, y=20)
    vieux = Label(frame4, text="Vieux à donf'", image=portrait_4, compound="top")
    vieux.place(x=260, y=280)

# VALIDATION DES INFOS DE COURSE
    validation = Button(frame3, text="VALIDER", font="Futura 18", bg="whitesmoke", fg="green", highlightcolor="red", command=config, border="0")
    validation.place(x=240, y=520)
    validation = Button(frame3, text="ANNULER", font="Futura 18", bg="whitesmoke", fg="red", highlightcolor="red", command=configurer, border="0")
    validation.place(x=350, y=520)


# FONCTION CHRONOMETRE

def chrono():
        global temps, ticks, nw, fenetre_ppale2
        ticks += 1
        minutes, secondes = divmod(ticks, 1000)
        heures, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
        temps_format = "{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(heures, minutes, secondes)
        temps.set(temps_format)
        fenetre_ppale2.after(1, chrono)


def lancer():
    global frame3, frame4, portrait_1, portrait_2, portrait_3, portrait_4, frame1, fenetre_ppale2
    fenetre_ppale.destroy()
    fenetre_ppale2 = Tk()
    fenetre_ppale2.geometry("1720x1080+10+10")

    # GESTION DES IMAGES
    #image1 = Image.open("images/alpha_romeo.png")
    image2 = Image.open("images/flag.png")
    #fond = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
    drapo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
    # INITIALISATION DESIMAGES
    dessin1 = Image.open("images/portrait_satanas.png")
    dessin2 = Image.open("images/portrait_folle.png")
    dessin3 = Image.open("images/portrait_sorciere.png")
    dessin4 = Image.open("images/portrait_vieux.png")
    portrait_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(dessin1)
    portrait_2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(dessin2)
    portrait_3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(dessin3)
    portrait_4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(dessin4)
    #frame3.place_forget()
    #frame4.place_forget()
    frame0 = Frame(fenetre_ppale2, border=0, pady=0, padx=0, bg="whitesmoke")
    frame0.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, height=120)
    cnvg = Canvas(frame0, width=600, height=100, bg="whitesmoke")
    cnvg.place(x=0, y=0)
    cnvg.create_image(0, 0, image=drapo, anchor="nw")
    cnvd = Canvas(frame0, width=600, height=100, bg="whitesmoke")
    cnvd.place(x=1100, y=0)
    cnvd.create_image(0, 0, image=drapo, anchor="nw")


    # LABEL DU CHRONO
    global temps, ticks
    temps = tkinter.StringVar()
    ticks = 0
    temps.set("00:00:000")
    label_temps = Label(frame0, textvariable=temps, font=("Futura", 36), bg="whitesmoke")
    label_temps.place(x=750, y=0)
    fenetre_ppale2.after(10, chrono)
    chrono()

    # RECUPERATION DES DONNEES DE LA COURSE
    with open('configcourse.json', 'r') as fic:
        data = json.load(fic)

    # PILOTE 1
    frame1 = Frame(fenetre_ppale2, width=573, height=800, bg="brown",  pady=10, padx=10)
    frame1.place(x=191, y=121)


    lbl_frame1 = Label(frame1, text=data['Pilote 1'], font="Futura 42 bold", padx=20, bg="brown", fg="white")
    lbl_frame1.place(relx=0.5, y=50, anchor="center")
    #cnvh = Canvas(frame1, width=100, height=100, bg="whitesmoke")
    #cnvh.place(x=20, y=100)
   # cnvh.create_image(master="frame1", x=0, y=0, image=data['Portrait pilote 1'], anchor="center")


    portrait_pilote_1 = Label(frame1, image=data["Portrait pilote 1"], compound="top", border="0")
    portrait_pilote_1.place(master=frame1, relx=0.5, y=120, anchor="center")


    # PILOTE 2
    frame2 = Frame(fenetre_ppale2, width=573, height=800, bg="navy", pady=10, padx=10)
    frame2.place(x=955, y=121)
    lbl_frame2 = Label(frame2, text=data['Pilote 2'], font="Futura 42 bold", padx=20, bg="navy", fg="white")
    lbl_frame2.place(relx=0.5, y=50, anchor="center")

    fenetre_ppale2.mainloop()

# MENU PRINCIPAL
mon_menu = Menu(fenetre_ppale)

fichier_menu = Menu(mon_menu)
fichier_menu.add_command(label="configurer", command=configurer)
fichier_menu.add_command(label="Lancer", command=lancer)
fichier_menu.add_command(label="Quitter", command=quitter)
mon_menu.add_cascade(label="Fichier", menu=fichier_menu)

# IMAGE DE LANCEMENT
#img = PhotoImage(file="alpha_romeo.png")
lbl_image = Label(fenetre_ppale, image=fond)
lbl_image.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


fenetre_ppale.config(menu=mon_menu, bg="whitesmoke")

fenetre_ppale.mainloop()




I try to display the picture choose by driver from "configurer" window in "Lancer" window.

It is better to post the full error traceback.  Also sample content of configcourse.json.

the configcourse.json :  {"Pilote 1": "Jean", "Pilote 2": "Serge", "Voiture 1": "Aston Martin Vantage GT3", "Voiture 2": "McLaren 720S GT3", "Portrait pilote 1": "portrait_2", "Portrait pilote 2": "portrait_6", "Temps de course": 5}

image=data["Portrait pilote 1"] in Label(...) will raise exception because image option expects instance of PhotoImage(), not string.

@acw1668 Thanks, I should have thought of that! So I need to make a correspondence between what is recorded in json and the PhotoImage instance.
